How to convert Vertex Location calculations to Pixel Shader side
For my final project in my shaders class, I am supposed to convert the vertex displacement calculations to occur on the pixel shader side instead. I am doing this in XNA Monogame. My professor made a drawing of the problem on the whiteboard but has been very vague and a bit frustrating on how to actually make this calculation, I was hoping I could get some help here. Here's the general idea:

My Vertex Shader currently looks like this

How could I make it so that the displacement is per-pixel as opposed to per-vertex?
Thanks
I haven't been able to really try anything, as I'm not sure where to start this calculation.
